# Замена символов не затрагивая последних четырех

Tags: php, строки, замена

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста как лучше сделать.
Есть код:

```
$order = "1234567894567";  
$len_numb = strlen($order) - 4;  
$c_numb = substr_replace($order, '************', 0, $len_numb);
```

где в $order приходит строка, в которой мне нужно заменить все символы кроме последних четырех на * . Я написал решение, правда работает кривовато, так как может прийти больше чем 16 знаков, подскажите как оптимизировать под любую длину строки. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo str_pad('', strlen($order)-4, '*') . substr($order,-4);
```

Comment: мб проще`str_pad(substr($order, -4), strlen($order), '*', STR_PAD_LEFT)` ?

Comment: @teran не знаю, насчет проще, но клёвше :)

Comment: Ребята, а какой тогда валидней? :)

Comment: Да, одно и тоже, на самом деле